# Unable to get emails sent by PHP mail function because of another mail server

Tags: php, email, mail-server, webmail

I'm created a website with PHP on a Linux web hosting package. Normally I will get emails sent by its contact form that produced by PHP Mail() function. But this time, it is a strange case for me.
My customer company has a mail server. If I send an email via my personal email on Gmail, they will get it on their mail server. But when I send emails via contact form, emails go to webmail on website hosting package.
I've removed all email accounts on this host, also I removed DNS MX record from it, but still I can not receive emails sent by contact form on the company mail server accounts.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the web server running UNIX or Windows? Is PHP configured with sendmail or an SMTP server?

Comment: It's running on Unix, and as I said, contact form uses PHP Mail() function for sending emails.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems from your question the webshoting provider is also your email hosting provider. The way you explained the problem leads me to the conclusion that your PHP script uses the mail() function which will internally call the MTA (like sendmail) to send the email.

Now what seems to happen here is that PHP is sending the mail through mail() function which is passing it on to the local MTA (like sendmail) which is checking the local configuration. In the local config it seems to find the recipient domain as a local domain and deliver the mail locally to the user. In this case the email is not even leaving the webhoster's server.

As this is not what you expect, you have 2 possibilities if you do not have influence to the MTA's configuration (what i think you dont have).

1. I would propose (if possible) to not use the mail() function. There are ready to use SMTP classes which will connect to a SMTP server of your coice to send the email to. In that way you can avoid this problem. You should find something in the [PHP Classes Repository](http://www.phpclasses.org).
2. Send the email to a different domain if possible. That way the MTA has to check DNS and send the email to another SMTP server for delivery.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to establish is how you are sending emails (sendmail or SMTP). Then, whether your emails are a) not sent at all or b) getting rejected by the destination mail server.

I'd check all available logs (source and destination mail servers and daemons). See if mail() itself is erroring. Try using sendmail/smtp directly.

If its the destination server rejecting the mail based on its spam score, try setting [SPF records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) to enable the web server to send mail *legally*.

Answer (score 0):

If your email function "mail($to,$subject,$message)" is not working then you need to check the server configuration. Now it is enable or not . 
For more details, 
see here :  https://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/when-phps-mail-function-doesnt-work/